# Свои поля в the_content

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как в функцию the_content вывести свои произвольные поля на страницы page.php

Стоит плагин Pods, где создал свои поля

В single запись вставляются доп поля, всё работает, а как в функцию the_content вставить не знаю.

```
<?php echo pods_field_display( 'office' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> а как в функцию the_content вставить не знаю.

С помощью хука [the_content](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/the_content)

Например в конце поста:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_end');
function the_end( $text ){
    return $text . pods_field_display( 'office' );
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, получилось. А больше полей как вывести, попробовал так, не работает `add_filter('the_content', 'the_end'); function the_end( $text ){ return $text . pods_field_display( 'office', '2', '4' );`

Comment: @Pavel Если получилось - надо отметить вопрос решённым.